# WooCommerce: Simplify/Clear the checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

According to the attached screenshot:

1. How can I remove the yellow marked content from the checkout page?
2. How can I change the text and remove/change the link for the text marked with a green arrow?
3. I point out the green box [`Voucher 4889 has been added to your cart`] - how can I remove the link right to the text [also marked with a yellow box]?

This should result in a very clear and simplified checkout form.

---

Update: Any CSS and template modification are not an option as the checkout has to be simplified in a plugin which will be installed and there is no way to *force* the webmaster to apply the modifications. The plugin should modify the checkout page on the fly for certain products.

[image]

Comment: You have a lot of elements here all coming from different PHP files the ideal situation would be to edit child versions of these template files but that is a lot to explain in StackOverflow. 

so you have another option of using css classes set to display none that specifically target the .woocommerce-checkout in your body element

Comment: @BradHolmes Please read my update. Your suggestion is not an option. Aren't there not any WooCommerce `Actions` which can do it?

Comment: most of the elements you are attempting to adjust have zero to do with woocommerce, the nav, the search, breadcrumb and the side bar are all parts of the theme and not woocommerce, the woocommerce parts are just being wraped inside the theme templates. so you would need to adjust the theme or push a css file in your plugin to override these parts but in many cases the clases would be theme specific

Comment: @BradHolmes Yep, I am now studying the checkout page and I see it. OK, is it a possible solution to create _own_ checkout page where I can put the 3 fields and the enabled payment gateways? Would you have a link to the documentation regarding this?

Comment: i would start with the woocommerce hooks but you would be rebuilding the whole checkout process 
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html